# Não consigo fazer o dataBinding AndroidStudioKotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding

[image: CrieSeuPersonagem]

[image: crie_seu_personagem-Layout Main]

Simplesmente não consigo fazer o binding funcionar e quando boto o mouse por cima aparece o seguinte erro : Unresolved reference: CrieSeuPersonagemBinding
Just cant make the binding work and when i put the mouse over it shows the following error : Unresolved reference: CrieSeuPersonagemBinding

Answer (score 0):

Quando você cria uma activity, existe a opção de criá-la junto com o layout, ai o binding é automático. Depois de criar é só botar id nos componentes desse layout e utilizá-los no código da própria activity, por exemplo:

Se no seu xml existe um Button com id "btnSalvar", na sua activity é só escrever esse btnSalvar dentro de algum método (pode ser do onCreate) e botar por exemplo:
btnSalvar.setOnClickListener{ coisa que vc quer que o botão faça ao ser clicado }. Depois o nome btnSalvar vai estar em vermelho pra importar, ai é só apertar Alt Enter pra importar.

A mesma coisa vale pra um TextView, que seria pelo .text, conseguindo assim pegar o texto que está dentro dele.

```
class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    btnSalvar.setOnClickListener{ 
         var destreza = editDestreza.text
         var inteligencia = editInteligencia.text
         var sabedoria = editSabedoria.text
         var forca = editForca.text
    }
  }
}
```

editDestreza, editInteligencia, editSabedoria e editForca são os ids de cada EditText no layout xml

Comment: Onde fica essa opção de criá-la junto com o layout?

Comment: quando vc cria a activity aparece a opção Generate Layout File

Comment: Mas esse layout já foi gerado assim.

Comment: Sim, mas a activity por padrão já se comunica com o layout através do setContentView, que no seu código está removido e estaria na linha do val binding :CrieSeuPersonagem. Vou editar minha resposta para clarear o que está acontecendo

Comment: Outra coisa, dentro do seu xml tem que ter um tools:context=".nomeDaSuaActivity" para ocorrer o binding, senão o aplicativo vai crashar.
Esse tools:context=".nomeDaSuaActivity" seria uma propriedade do componente Layout, pode ficar embaixo do android:layout_height="match_parent" só que antes da setinha ">"

Comment: val editDestreza : EditText = findViewById(R.id.editDestreza)
Se eu quiser referenciar o editText editDestreza eu preciso fazer isso, caso contrário dá Unresolved Reference.

Comment: Sim, ocorre porque não existe um setContentView da própria activity, como está escrito no meu código.

Comment: No meu código por exemplo eu não precisei utilizar o findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar), eu apenas utilizei o btnSalvar solto, o que acontece é que esse btnSalvar vai ficar pintado de vermelho, pois não foi importado ainda o layout, ai é só clicar no btnSalvar e apertar Alt Enter que importa o layout automaticamente

Comment: Cara, se eu fosse você criava outro projeto do zero com uma empty activity, depois disso é só botar um EditText no layout e dentro dele botar um id, que seria assim

android:id="@+id/edt_Destreza"

Ai depois escreve "edt_Destreza" dentro da sua activity no onCreate . Só isso já vai identificar automaticamente o componente. Esse edt_Destreza que vc acabou de escrever vai ficar escrito em vermelho, ai é só botar o mouse em cima e escolher a opção de importar

Answer (score 0):

Elias, tentei fazer dessa forma mas as opções não contêm importar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
val destreza = editDestreza.text.toString().toInt()
}
}
nas opções do alt enter não há nada sobre importar.